# Ask great questions, enter to win a prize!

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

We kicked off a Topic of the Week series on a few other sites, and now we're bringing it to Photo Stack Exchange! The basic idea is to increase the content we have about hot or underrepresented topics. Feel free to leave suggestions for future topics.

### Congratulations to dpollitt, winner of Business of Photography Week!

**How it works:** We will designate one topic each week, and each person who asks a question relating to that topic will be eligible to win a prize.

**How to enter:** Ask a question relating to the topic of the week, and tag it accordingly (each week, specific tags will be listed here). Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win a book of your choice (under $50).

**Choosing the topic of the week:** Topics are chosen based on community input. If you have suggestions for next week's topic, please leave them as answers to this post.

**Dates:** Each contest will start at 10 AM on a Tuesday and end at 10 AM the following Tuesday.

### There is no contest for the week of 1/31/12.

Participation has been low; there were only four questions asked by two people for Business of Photography, which was tied for the first place community suggested topic. The other top topic, Artificial Lighting, doesn't have specific enough tags to track. I'm suspending this contest indefinitely.

**Fine Print:** This contest is open to all users across the globe, but the book of the winner's choice must be available for purchase online so that Stack Exchange can easily buy and send it. The book does not have to be related to the topic of that week, but it should be related to photography. Questions must remain open and have a positive score in order to be eligible. You must include the current theme's tag(s) in order to be have your question counted, but feel free to include additional tags that you feel belong with the question. Each user may only win one weekly contest every 8 weeks.

**Previous Weekly Challenge Topics:**

- Jan. 3 - 10: Macro photography (Winner: [rfusca](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1917/rfusca))
- Jan 10 - 17: Portrait photography (Winner: [MikeW](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4191/mikew))
- Jan 17 - 31: Business of Photography (Winner: [dpollitt](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4892/dpollitt))

Comment: Great idea, I can see that generating some good questions.

Comment: are we setting a limit like in cooking.se of once per 8 weeks on winning?

Comment: Yes, updated in the post accordingly. I hope that doesn't discourage anyone from asking questions every week, though. ;)

Comment: I've been using SE sites for a while, and been more active on photo.se lately, but I didn't know about this "contest" before now. I probably would've asked a few questions to get in the draw, if I knew about it. Maybe not enough people knew about it?

Comment: @HåkonK.Olafsen I've had an ad linking to this meta post running on the sidebar of the main site for about three weeks before I shut this down; it's also been "featured" on meta since it began. It's also been discussed in chat. I'm not really sure what more I can do; I'm open to starting it up again at some future date if there's enough interest, but I'm giving it a break for now.

Comment: I saw the sidebar now, and I have to admit that I haven't really looked at the sidebar at all (on any SE sites) before. I might have noticed the existence, but I'm too used to sidebars being either ads or some form of a "menu" to really notice what's in them. I haven't used the chat before either, but one more person (me) joining in wouldn't really change the reason for stopping the lottery.

Comment: Hmmm.  Have to admit that this is the first time I've noticed the sidebar link and clicked on it....

Answer (score 5):

### Topic Suggestion: **Artificial Lighting**

Ask questions related to using, setting up, and perfecting artificial lighting for portraiture, macro, still life, or any other form of photography that can benefit from artificial lighting. Lighting forms can include flash, continuous, any form of light control such as diffusion, bounce, concentrators, etc.

**Tags:** Flash, Lighting

Comment: suggestions of what tags we would track for it?

Comment: Doesn't this answer belong over on http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1760/would-you-be-interested-in-a-topic-of-the-week-contest/1777#1777?

Comment: @mattdm Here is good. This thread will be updated every week, so it will be both a repository of suggestions and a record of topics we've already covered. Had I gotten more feedback on the other thread, I would've moved the answers here...still keeping your idea in mind of tying to PotW theme.

Comment: Great topic idea, although very broad.  An alternative would be a theme like Portrait Photography, where you could ask about lighting, posing, backdrops, equipment, lens choices and so forth.  Although I guess that's just as broad, if not more so :)

Comment: I went with Portrait as the theme for this week because it's easier to track by tags than "artificial lighting" is.

Comment: @jrista suggestions for tags would be excellent, since that's how I track entries. I'd like to limit each theme to 2-3 relevant tags for simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

**Business of Photography**

Questions should deal with the professional side of photography - marketing, dealing with clients, contracts, etc

Tags to track: [business]

Comment: Topic for the week of Jan 17 - 24, 2012.

Comment: Six people upvoted this topic, but only two have asked questions so far! [cue encouragement for more people to submit questions on this topic]

Comment: I'll drop a rash of questions tonight and see if that gets the ball rollings.

Answer (score 2):

**Composition**

Questions should deal with the composition of photographs.

Tags to track:  [composition]

Answer (score 2):

**Filters**

Questions should deal with filters.  Polarized, ND, Grad ND, UV,colored, etc

Tags to track: [filters]

Answer (score 2):

**Landscape Photography**

Questions should deal with photographing any form of landscape, including those that are primarily "skyscapes" or "waterscapes".

Tags to track: [landscape]

Answer (score 2):

**Food Photography**

Questions should deal with photographic techniques, intriguing arrangements, lighting ideas, etc. for capturing the best food photographs.

Tags to track: [food-photography]

Answer (score 2):

**Street Photography**

Questions should deal with techniques, gear, legal.

Tags to track: [street-photography]

Answer (score 1):

**Wedding Photography**

Questions should deal with weddings, engagement photos, etc.  This could cover either actually taking the pictures, dealing with clients, dealing with family, etc.

Tags to track: [wedding]

Answer (score 1):

**Astrophotography**

Questions should deal with equipment and techniques for astrophotography.

Tags to track: [astrophotography], [moon], [aurora]

Answer (score 1):

#### History

Questions about influential persons, styles, photographs, schools and techniques from past.

Tags to track: [[history](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)]